# Calculate a Simple Moving Average Crossover using SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, quantitative-finance

How do I achieve a Simple Moving Average crossover? I've looked at some other example/questions ask on here, however they all seem to use an ID column, my table does not have an ID and uses the TIME as a unique field.

SMA Cross over is used to determine a trend in the stock and/or foreign exchange market. For the sake of brevity, the proposed query output below is a 10 and 20 day moving average. However in the real world I will be using a 60 and 270 day average.
Following on from the [ATR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969481/calculate-the-average-true-range-using-sql-server-2014)  (big thanks to [Lucero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88558/lucero)), there are two answers for calculating an average. The first ATR average was much faster than the second.

---

I have the following data:

```
TIME               BID-OPEN BID-HIGH BID-LOW BID-CLOSE
28/01/1981 22:00    130.34  130.34  130.34  130.34
29/01/1981 22:00    130.24  130.24  130.24  130.24
02/02/1981 22:00    126.91  126.91  126.91  126.91
03/02/1981 22:00    128.46  128.46  128.46  128.46
04/02/1981 22:00    128.59  128.59  128.59  128.59
05/02/1981 22:00    129.63  129.63  129.63  129.63
09/02/1981 22:00    129.27  129.27  129.27  129.27
10/02/1981 22:00    129.24  129.24  129.24  129.24
11/02/1981 22:00    128.24  128.24  128.24  128.24
12/02/1981 22:00    127.48  127.48  127.48  127.48
17/02/1981 22:00    127.81  127.81  127.81  127.81
18/02/1981 22:00    128.48  128.48  128.48  128.48
19/02/1981 22:00    126.61  126.61  126.61  126.61
23/02/1981 22:00    127.35  127.35  127.35  127.35
24/02/1981 22:00    127.39  127.39  127.39  127.39
25/02/1981 22:00    128.52  128.52  128.52  128.52
26/02/1981 22:00    130.1   130.1   130.1   130.1
02/03/1981 22:00    132.01  132.01  132.01  132.01
03/03/1981 22:00    130.56  130.56  130.56  130.56
04/03/1981 22:00    130.86  130.86  130.86  130.86
05/03/1981 22:00    129.93  129.93  129.93  129.93
09/03/1981 22:00    131.12  131.12  131.12  131.12
10/03/1981 22:00    130.46  130.46  130.46  130.46
11/03/1981 22:00    129.95  129.95  129.95  129.95
12/03/1981 22:00    133.19  133.19  133.19  133.19
16/03/1981 22:00    134.68  134.68  134.68  134.68
17/03/1981 22:00    133.92  133.92  133.92  133.92
18/03/1981 22:00    134.22  134.22  134.22  134.22
19/03/1981 22:00    133.46  133.46  133.46  133.46
23/03/1981 22:00    135.69  135.69  135.69  135.69
24/03/1981 22:00    134.67  134.67  134.67  134.67
```

---

The proposed query output below, an average of the [BID-CLOSE] values over the last 10 and 20 days, which will give an output of this:

(ROUND to 2 decimal places)

```
TIME             BID-CLOSE FAST-SMA SLOW-SMA    
28/01/1981 22:00    130.34  NULL    NULL
29/01/1981 22:00    130.24  NULL    NULL
02/02/1981 22:00    126.91  NULL    NULL
03/02/1981 22:00    128.46  NULL    NULL
04/02/1981 22:00    128.59  NULL    NULL
05/02/1981 22:00    129.63  NULL    NULL
09/02/1981 22:00    129.27  NULL    NULL
10/02/1981 22:00    129.24  NULL    NULL
11/02/1981 22:00    128.24  NULL    NULL
12/02/1981 22:00    127.48  128.84  NULL
17/02/1981 22:00    127.81  128.59  NULL
18/02/1981 22:00    128.48  128.41  NULL
19/02/1981 22:00    126.61  128.39  NULL
23/02/1981 22:00    127.35  128.27  NULL
24/02/1981 22:00    127.39  128.15  NULL
25/02/1981 22:00    128.52  128.04  NULL
26/02/1981 22:00    130.1   128.12  NULL
02/03/1981 22:00    132.01  128.40  NULL
03/03/1981 22:00    130.56  128.63  NULL
04/03/1981 22:00    130.86  128.97  128.90
05/03/1981 22:00    129.93  129.18  128.89
09/03/1981 22:00    131.12  129.45  128.93
10/03/1981 22:00    130.46  129.83  129.11
11/03/1981 22:00    129.95  130.09  129.18
12/03/1981 22:00    133.19  130.67  129.41
16/03/1981 22:00    134.68  131.29  129.66
17/03/1981 22:00    133.92  131.67  129.90
18/03/1981 22:00    134.22  131.89  130.14
19/03/1981 22:00    133.46  132.18  130.41
23/03/1981 22:00    135.69  132.67  130.82
24/03/1981 22:00    134.67  133.14  131.16
```

SMA = Simple Moving Average

Comment: Sounds like a great project! Let us know if you have a question! However, when you edit your post to include a question, pls also tell us how you tried to achieve the expected results. SO is a Q/A site, not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point, you would want to use an avg() over(), something like this:

```
select time, 
    [bid-close],
    avg([bid-close]) over (order by time rows 9 preceding) as [fast-sma]
    avg([bid-close]) over (order by time rows 19 preceding) as [slow-sma]
from table
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't clear in the question, my fault. The values that are part of the initial average calculation must show NULL. The reason is after this query i'm going to add two additional columns, which say "IF [FAST-SMA] > [SLOW-SMA] = 1, 0" and "IF [FAST-SMA] < [SLOW-SMA] = 1, 0"

Comment: That's why I said this is a starting point. If you're not sure where to go next, you can use the [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function in a [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement to determine which columns should be set to null. Let me know if you get stuck, and I can help...but might be good if you take a crack at it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can block the SMA from being calculated for the first *n* rows by wrapping the window functions in a condition for the `ROW_NUMBER()`.

To detect positive and negative crossovers you can use multi-conditionals checking both the current and previous values using a `LAG()` function.

This should give you what you need:

```
WITH sma_table AS
(
    SELECT
        time,
        bid_open,
        bid_high,
        bid_low,
        bid_close,
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) > 9 
             THEN AVG(bid_close) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS 9 PRECEDING) 
        END AS sma_10,
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) > 19
             THEN AVG(bid_close) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS 19 PRECEDING) 
        END AS sma_20
    FROM your_table
)
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN bid_close > sma_10 
              AND LAG(bid_close) OVER (ORDER BY time) <= LAG(sma_10) OVER (ORDER BY time) 
              THEN 1
         WHEN bid_close < sma_10 
              AND LAG(bid_close) OVER (ORDER BY time) >= LAG(sma_10) OVER (ORDER BY time) 
              THEN -1
    END AS sma_10_crossover,
    CASE WHEN bid_close > sma_20 
              AND LAG(bid_close) OVER (ORDER BY time) <= LAG(sma_20) OVER (ORDER BY time) 
              THEN 1
         WHEN bid_close < sma_20 
              AND LAG(bid_close) OVER (ORDER BY time) >= LAG(sma_20) OVER (ORDER BY time) 
              THEN -1
    END AS sma_20_crossover
FROM sma_table
```